# Grabbing text from text files with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have tons of text files from which ones I want to grab the text and display it on one webpage. Also I would like to have the file name of those files added at the top of every text grabbed.

e.g:

file name

text from file name

---

file name

text from file name

---

...

Any idea how can I do this  using JavaScript?

If is not js I'll be happy with php as well.

Thanks :)
Vic

Comment: Just use AJAX get calls to retrieve the text files, and create a new `<div>` with a header containing the filename, and a paragraph containing the retrieved text.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked out jquery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function?  i think it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

From client side javascript, you can't do this as you can't get a list of all the text files. It would also be very slow.

For php, see the [opendir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) function to get the list of files, and the [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function to display their contents.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP it's pretty simple.

```
$file = 'path/to/file/';    
$contents = fread($file,'r');
fclose($file);
```